# Getting the fieldnames from the field-symbols

Tags: abap

I need to get the field names in the field-symbol `<itab>`, so that I can use the names for the field catalog of ALV.

So I used cl_abap_structdescr but it throws me always an error.
I tried this with an internal table and i had the expected result, but I have to use the field symbol instead of internal table.

```
ASSIGN lo_itab->* TO <itab>

data: go_struct type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
      gt_comp   type abap_component_tab,
      gs_comp   type abap_componentdescr.


  go_struct ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( <itab> ).
  gt_comp = go_struct->get_components( ).

  loop at gt_comp into gs_comp.

      PERFORM fill_fieldcat USING : 
     gs_comp-name      ''       gs_comp-name
   .
  endloop.
```

this is the error;
[image]

Comment: do you want to use field symbol for gs_comp?

Comment: I need to get the fieldnames in the field symbol "<itab>"

Comment: you are already assigning ASSIGN lo_itab->* TO <itab>. can you share the error also?

Comment: I've added the error message on runtime. see the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<itab>` is obviously an **internal table**, its type is "table", not "structure"! (also see the short dump, it says that `describe_by_data` returned a type `cl_abap_tabledescr` which is not compatible with the type of target `go_struct`, i.e. `cl_abap_structdescr`)

So you must first get its table type, then get the type of its lines (I assume here that it's a structured type, but it could be other types in some other situations).

```
data: go_table type ref to cl_abap_tabledescr.
      go_struct type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
      gt_comp   type abap_component_tab,
      gs_comp   type abap_componentdescr.

go_table ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( <itab> ).
go_struct ?= go_table->get_table_line_type( ).
gt_comp = go_struct->get_components( ).
...
```

Comment: I am new to abap and still learning by myself. Thank You for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

As you are assigning reference type to another reference type therefore you getting dump.  Define a structure type and pass in place of  as i did in the below example. You will not get any dump.

```
data: go_struct type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
      gt_comp   type abap_component_tab,
      gs_comp   type abap_componentdescr.

  DATA ls_spfli TYPE spfli.
  go_struct ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( ls_spfli ).
  gt_comp = go_struct->get_components( ).

  loop at gt_comp into gs_comp.

*      PERFORM fill_fieldcat USING :
*     gs_comp-name      ''       gs_comp-name
*   .
  endloop.
```

Comment: go_struct ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( <itab> ). --that line doesn't work. always having a runtime error.

Comment: I have updated the answer , i believe you will not face any dump now.

Comment: This is example only, you can update as per your requirement.

Comment: That will definitely work, but is there any other way to get the fields in the field symbol?

Comment: If field symbol is a structure then you can use ASSIGN COMPONENT 'NAMEOFCOMPONENT' OF STRUCTURE <fs_struct> to  <fs_fieldname>.